# String array element print in new line

Tags: php, arrays

Here's my code:

```
<?php

function spilt($number){
    $array = array("john doe alex hales johnny johnn arnold ronnie",
                   "john doe alex hales johnny johnn arnold ronnie",
                   "john doe alex hales johnny johnn arnold ronnie");

    for ($i=0; $i <count($array) ; $i++) {
        $string =  explode(" ", $array[$i]);
        echo"<br>";
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($string); $j++) {
            echo $string[$j]." ";
            if ($j+1 == $number ) {
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}

spilt(3);
```

1. when I pass 1 to the function then all the array elements should break like this:

   ```
   john  
   doe 
   alex 
   hales 
   johnny 
   johnn 
   arnold 
   ronnie
   ```
2. when I pass 2 to the function, the output should be like this:

   ```
   john doe 
   alex hales  
   johnny johnn 
   arnold ronnie
   ```
3. When I pass 3 to the function, the output should be like this, and so on:

   ```
   john doe alex
   hales johnny johnn
   arnold ronnie
   ```

is it possible?

Comment: I don't get it, what is your issue? You've given the outcomes and your code but what shouldn't be happening that is or vice versa.

Comment: Just use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

Comment: my code is run perfectly i just want when i pass value to function all array elements breaks according to my passing value the output which i have want i have write above. i didn't get how to solve it. code works fine

Comment: *my code is run perfectly* - Then you have no issue right or you have not explained it aptly in your OP.

Comment: bro can you help me according to my output which i have want? @Script47

Comment: @JomPom Please try to act a bit more professionally, badgering people will only make them less likely to help you in future.  And as somebody already pointed out, PHP can do this already with array_chunk()

Comment: @GordonM you are right. did i not well explain the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only problem is this: `if ($j+1 == $number )`.

That condition means you're only inserting a new line when `$j+1` is *exactly equal to* `$number`. You need to see if it's divisible by `$number` instead.

```
if (($j + 1) % $number == 0)
```